# FileZilla: "A file with that name is already being transferred" but no file in queue

Tags: windows, filezilla

I use FileZilla 3.29.0 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I was trying to edit a file, and got the error message:

> A file with that name is already being transferred.

There is no file in queue. How can I fix the issue? I don't want to restart FileZilla as I have a few things going on.

---

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to upload a file to that directory? If so, create a small dummy file named "testdummy.txt" and be sure it has a line of dummy code and not zero byte, and then try to upload the file again and see what message that gives you about overwriting it and such. I assume you do not have access to the FTP server to look over logs and check the account FTP mailbox permissions so try that as I believe it you have read-only access then you won't be able to modify existing files including rename. Consider an FTP rename via command prompt too and also renaming the "testdummy.txt" afterwards.